# How to change or avoid default value in SQL-Profiler call? | SQL Profiler | SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, sql-server-profiler

**How to change or avoid default value in SQL-Profiler call?**

SQL Server 2019/2017 Profiler set default values for all parameters of a stored procedure. however, It's additional and gives errors in execution. therefore, I have to remove default value lines all the time otherwise script gets failed with the error "*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.*". How can I avoid these default value lines in the profiler call? Refer to the highlighted lines in the below picture.

```
set @p1=default

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.
```

*Note: All early versions do not add default value, am facing this issue in SQL-2019/2017 versions.*

[image]